# Accumulation points and boundrary points

Tags: complex-analysis

I have trouble seeing the difference between these two. If we have open set $S$ inside disk $|z|<1$ it's boundary points lie on the curve $|z|=1$. But isn't every point in  $|z|=1$ also a accumulation point?

set $S=\{z: 0<|z-z_0|<1\}$ has boundary points in $|z-z_0|=1$ and also the point $z_0$ itself. Aren't these also accumulation points?

Comment: True! translation error sorry.

Comment: Well, the points with $\lvert z-z_0\rvert = \frac{1}{2}$ for example are accumulation points but not boundary points. For boundary points that are not accumulation points, you need a set with isolated points, say $S = \mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{C}$. Then every point of $S$ is a boundary point, but no point is an accumulation point of $S$.

Comment: So interior points are also accumulation points in open set?

Comment: For subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or similar spaces. An accumulation point of $S$ is a point $x$ such that every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $S$. Since a neighbourhood of a point contains infinitely points (in spaces like $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is not true for all topological spaces), every interior point of a set is an accumulation point.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :)